# Cannot get Custom Attribute Finder to appear in WSO2 Identity Server Console

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I did some development of a custom AttributeFinder for WSO2 4.6 several years ago, and I am trying to reproduce that old development on one of my original WSO2 4.6 instances, but I cannot get the AttributeFinder to appear in the WSO2 IS Console in Extensions.  I know that 4.6 is old, but I just want to get this working with 4.6 first.

- I've built the AttributeFinder in Eclipse successfully
- Put a copy of the JAR in E:\WSO2\wso2is-4.6.0\repository\components\lib
- Put copies of ojdbc6.jar and classes12.jar into E:\WSO2\wso2is-4.6.0\repository\components\lib

[This AttributeFinder is supposed to get the attributes from an Oracle DB]

- I've updated E:\WSO2\wso2is-4.6.0\repository\conf\security\entitlement.properties by adding:

> PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.3=my.myAttributeFinder
>   my.MyAttributeFinder.1=databaseUrl,jdbc:oracle:thin:@//192.168.0.xxx:1521/xxxorcl
>   my.MyAttributeFinder.2=userName,hr
>   my.MyAttributeFinder.3=password,XXXX
>   my.MyACAttributeFinder.4=driverName,oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   my.MyACAttributeFinder.5=dbTableName,DB_FILTERS

Then I restarted the WSO2 but when I got into the console and look at Extensions/Attributes, it is only showing the default attributes/attributefinder.

As I said, I had this working awhile ago, so I'm sure that the code I used to build the attribute finder class/jar is ok, and the lines I had to add into entitlement.properties above are ok, but it just looks like WSO2 IS doesn't even "know" that I have a custom attribute finder installed, so I think I must be missing some step or something.

Can anyone tell me what else I need to get WSO2 IS to "see" my custom attributes?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

I just figure out what the problem was.  I had added my lines to the default, out-of-box entitlement.properties, and in particular, I had the Designator line:

> PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.3=my.myAttributeFinder

In the default entitlement.properties, there was already only one other PIP Designator lines, something like:

> ...Designator.1=...

What I didn't realize is that, apparently, the Designator numbering has to be **sequential**!

So, when I changed the line to:

> PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.2=my.myAttributeFinder

instead of:

> PIP.AttributeDesignators.Designator.3=my.myAttributeFinder

Then, the WSO2 IS picked up my custom finder ok!

Comment: i am using WSO2 IS 5.9.0 and 5.6.0. if i restart server after config the config is reloading it and my changes are removed. can you help what i have missed